# RavenDB Static Index field with Max() aggregation

Tags: ravendb

My documents have a "Comments" collection, and I'd like to index the "Last Commented Date". I have statically defined index already working for other fields, so there's nothing wrong with my index. But attempting to add this new field is not working. I simply cannot ever get any results when searching by it.

I've tried getting the max date with a Max() aggregation (note that I have to handle cases where there are no comments)

```
testlastcommented = doc.Comments.Count > 0 ? doc.Comments.Select(c => c.DateEntered).Max() : null
```

This complains that DynamicList does not support Max(). I could swear that I had an iteration of this using Max() that worked, but now I can't get that working. But regardless even when it wasn't throwing an error, I wasn't able to query on the field.

So then I tried by OrderByDescending/FirstOrDefault as an alternative to Max()

```
testlastcommented = doc.Comments.OrderByDescending(c => c.DateEntered).FirstOrDefault()
```

This indexes with no errors. But whatever I do, it's as if the field doesn't exist in the index. I can't get any results with known values.

I broke down and added a calculated "LastCommented" property to the document and indexed that. That obviously works, but I'd rather not have to store a calculated field in the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
testlastcommented = doc.Comments.Select(c => c.DateEntered)
                                .OrderByDescending(x => x)
                                .FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Nope, index errors: no overload for "OrderByDescending" takes 0 arguments.

Comment: What version of RavenDB are you running?

Comment: Here we go... this works! But why???

    doc.Comments.Select(c => c.DateEntered).OrderByDescending(c => c).FirstOrDefault()

Comment: I see now why my firstordefault wasnt working, nevermind :) But why is Max() not supported?

Comment: If you're taking the max of a value that's in a collection in the same doc, then you're right - it *should* work.  I think it's just a bug.  What version are you running?

Comment: You might also try `.Select(c => c.DateEntered).Cast<DateTime>().Max()` - but I don't think you should *have* to do that.

Comment: I'll play with this more later and write up a bug report for H.R.